# Where do unanswered questions go to die?

Tags: discussion, support

I was checking back and my original unanswered question "Scrub PDF Malware Files to XPS Format" seems to have been removed from Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange (as in I've searched everywhere and can't find it) and is also not listed in my user account.  An exact duplicate of my original question is now located at [one of those clone sites](http://www.pythoneye.com/74_20503632/) and a few others.

Does the Stack Exchange network discard or delete old unanswered questions?  Why is my question missing from the site and now located at a clone site under a different author?

Comment: I suspect you fell under case 9 of this list http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: Yeah, that's some off topic stuff you got there...Shame if someone were to  delete it... Oh!